# regex to take into consideration line break

Tags: javascript, regex

The regex below replace the white space before the number with a comma:

```
var str="72 g tocirah snaeb 101 sgge 108 g darl 111 spuc loi 32  sinihccuz";
var result = str.replace(/ (\d+)/g, ", $1");
```

That work great, but when str is a multiline sentence like this:

```
var str="72 g tocirah snaeb
101 sgge
108 g darl
111 spuc loi
32  sinihccuz";
var result = str.replace(/ (\d+)/g, ", $1");
```

That doesn't work, so the regex isn't working normally. How to fix it so that it will take into consideration line break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\s` to represent any space character (including newlines).

Answer (score 1):

You want to *add* a comma before whitespace that's followed by a number? Then you can use

```
result = str.replace(/(?=\s+\d)/g, ",");
```